# Where's the shadow light pass gone (cycles)?

Tags: shadows, versions, viewlayers

I'm following a tutorial (very beginner here) which wants me to enable the "shadows" light pass in the view layer - the tutorial is in blender version 3.2, which [the docs say has this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.2/render/layers/passes.html#id2), but I'm using 3.5, [which doesn't](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.5/render/layers/passes.html#id2).

Has this moved? Is there somewhere I should look for equivalent functionality, or has this just been removed?

The usage of it is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YZzHn0iz8U&t=919s) from 13:40, if it makes any difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's just been renamed to *Shadow Catcher* (basically the same thing) - it's still in the View Layer properties under *Light > Other*:

[image: ShadowPass]

There's a good video on it's usage here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeVyu9DPmUk

Comment: Thanks - I'd missed that as Shadow Catcher was in version 3.2 as well, cheers!